# cheerio with ionic creation of API

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ionic-framework, cheerio

I am creating an ionic app. I'm using Cheerio with Node.js to scrape a site. I can't get the whole array back to localhost, it just returns the first object. How can I go about returning the entire array?

This is the scraping code (scraper.js)

```
const request = require('request')
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://mywebsite', (error, response, html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const art = $('article').each((i, el) => {
            const title = $(el)
                .find('.entry-title.mh-posts-grid-title')
                .text();
            const link = $(el)
                .find('a')
                .attr('href');
            const image = $(el)
                .find('.mh-thumb-icon.mh-thumb-icon-small-mobile')
                .text()
            const Arra = { title: [title], link: [link], image: [image] }
            exports.Arra = Arra
```

This is the code where I export the data (document.js)

```
const express = require("express");
const ok = require('./ok')
const app = express();
const porta = '8000'



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(ok.Arra);
})

app.listen(porta, () => {
    console.log(`Server ex ${porta}`);
});
```

Comment: It would help to see a sample of the data as well. You also are at least missing a couple closing tags in the scraper.js code.

Comment: Returns only the first array

Comment: what tags are missing?

Comment: 1) If you console.log('$ equals', $) what is shown in the console.  That is the sample data.
2) In the sample provided you are missing closing tags for the request line { , the if line { , and const art line {

Comment: could you explain me better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code posted is the sum total of your code then the issue is likely the missing closing tags. It should be as shown below:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const Arra = [];

request('https://mywebsite', (error, response, html) => {
    // reset Array on each call
    Arra = [];
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        console.log('the array I am going to iterate over is', $);
        const art = $('article').each((i, el) => {
            const title = $(el)
                .find('.entry-title.mh-posts-grid-title')
                .text();
            const link = $(el)
                .find('a')
                .attr('href');
            const image = $(el)
                .find('.mh-thumb-icon.mh-thumb-icon-small-mobile')
                .text();
            // you must push each result into the array otherwise you are just going to have one result.
            Arra.push({ title: [title], link: [link], image: [image] });
    } // close of .each block
  }// close of if block
 }// close of request block
exports.Arra = Arra;
```

Comment: she was very helpful

Comment: @paul glad to help, please click check box and accept as correct :)